# $m$ red and $n$ blue balls in a bag. Probability of acquiring a run of $k$ balls without replacement.

Tags: combinatorics

I have a bag containing $m$ red and $n$ blue balls. I draw balls one by one without replacement. Say I wish to find the probability of acquiring a run of $k$ balls, without replacement, before acquiring the first blue ball.

By considering the balls being drawn one by one (thus acquiring some factorials), I was able to reduce the probability down to $$\frac{\binom{m+n-k-1}{m-1}}{\binom{m+n}{m}} = \frac{m}{m+n} \times \frac{\binom{m}{k}}{\binom{m+n-1}{m}}$$ This suggests to me that there is a simple combinatoric way of doing this problem.

However, I am unable to picture how this would work. Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider all arrangements starting with $k$ red balls followed by $1$ blue ball. The remaining balls will be $m-k$ red balls and $n-1$ blue balls. Thus, there are $\binom{n+m-k-1}{m-k}$ arrangements starting with $k$ red balls followed by $1$ blue ball of the $\binom{n+m}{m}$ possible arrangements. Thus, the probability is
$$
\frac{\binom{n+m-k-1}{m-k}}{\binom{n+m}{m}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Either I misread your Question or you approached this totally wrong.

The probability drawing red on the first draw is $\frac{m}{m+n}
 $. Then your probabilities of drawing red on the ensuing (k-1) draws are respectively $\frac{m-1}{m-1+n},...,\frac{m-(k-1)}{m-(k-1)+n}
 $. If you multiply all those together, the numerator is $\frac{m!}{(m-k)!}
 $ and the denominator is $\frac{(m+n)!}{(m-k+n)!}$
 .

Comment: This is precisely how I acquired my result, almost brute-forceish. However, my question was for a combinatoric explanation of my simplified result.